# Why am I getting Stack Trace when I open Horizon?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail, horizon

I allocate enough memory for this. in php.ini memory_limit = 3G I don't understand why this happens. If anyone has come across this problem.
When I run рorizon with these settings.

```
'defaults' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        'connection' => 'redis',
        'queue' => ['default'],
        'balance' => 'auto',
        'maxProcesses' => 1,
        'maxTime' => 0,
        'maxJobs' => 0,
        'memory' => 2048,
        'tries' => 1,
        'timeout' => 200,
        'nice' => 0,
    ],
],

'environments' => [
 
    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'maxProcesses' => 400,
        ],
    ],
],
```

I am getting next errors:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(41): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#5 /var/www/html/artisan(36): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php on line 28
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php): Failed to open stream: Input/output error in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 33
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit178bef08a42940d39635a033dd116c7e::getLoader()
#1 /var/www/html/artisan(18): require('...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 33
PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): Failed to open stream: Input/output error in /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/artisan(18): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Repository/Adapter/AdapterInterface.php): Failed to open stream: Input/output error in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 571
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Repository/Adapter/AdapterInterface.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 571
PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Reflector.php): Failed to open stream: Input/output error in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 571
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Reflector.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 571
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Reflector" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php:227
```

I need to process a large number of requests and 400 is the optimal number of processes for proper operation

But when the maxProcess => 7 parameter is set, everything works fine. But it's too slow

All files are in place.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sail sail 779502 Mar 12 22:33 autoload_static.php
```

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sail sail   2629 Mar 12 18:41 autoload_real.php
```

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sail sail  4453 Mar  8 16:17 Reflector.php
```

Comment: It says there are a number of files which could not be opened. Have you bothered looking at any of them? Whether they exist? Whether permissions are correct?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did. All local files are in place

Comment: And does the user which this process runs under able to read them? You need to add all this info into your question rather that just saying it's fine in the comments.

Comment: You also have given the impression that this did work before, but has failed since you increased the nor to 400. What happens if you back that out?

Comment: It works if I change to maxProcesses => 7. Value greater than 7 output to errors